# (42,18): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `(', expecting `,', `;', or `='

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game in unity, where i will make a time system. But im getting this error "(42,18): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `(', expecting`,', `;', or`='" and i can not find out why i doesnt want work.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TimeManager : MonoBehaviour {

public int seconds = 0;
public int minutes = 0;
public int hours = 0;
public int days = 0;
public int year = 0;
public Text TotalTimePlayed;

void Start(){
    StartCoroutine(time());
}

void Update(){
    TotalTimePlayed = year + " Y" + days + " D" + hours + " H" + minutes + " M" + seconds + " S";
}

private void timeAdd(){
    seconds += 1;
    if(seconds >= 60){
        minutes = 1;
    }

    if(minutes >= 60){
        hours = 1;
    }

    if(hours >= 24){
        days = 1;
    }

    if(days >= 365){
        year = 1;
    }

    IEnumerator time(){
        while (true){
            timeAdd();
            yield return new WaitForSendons(1);
        }
    }
}
}
```

What would work better/at all? Right now im getting the error "(42,18): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `(', expecting`,', `;', or`='"

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That code doesn't produce any such error for me. I suggest you look for a left paren at character 18 on line 42 of whatever file the error is in.

Comment: one of the reasons you're getting downvotes is because we don't feel like counting the lines until we hit line 42.  You should let us know what line it is, perhaps with a comment in the code.

Comment: argh okay i will do, Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(42,18): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol (', expecting,', ;', or=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47723345/42-18-error-cs1525-unexpected-symbol-expecting-or)

Answer (score 0):

There is one unnecessary `}` at the end of your file. Simply remove it!

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerator time(){
    while (true){
        timeAdd();
        yield return new WaitForSendons(1);
    }
}
```

Take this "time()"function out from "timeAdd()"